# Menu option in android

Tags: android

After referring a lot of tutorials I came to know that instead of `Menu` they have `ActionBar` for `> API 10`. But i am using `API 7` sdk for my testing, I have used `Menus` to show text with `drawable images`. But only the text is coming and the drawable icon image is not showing in the menu option. Please help me to solve this.

My `XML`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <!--
             Single menu item
             Set id, icon and Title for each menu item
    -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/savedstory"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:minHeight="20dp"
        android:title="Saved Stories"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/setting"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:minHeight="20dp"
        android:title="Settings"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/Bookmark"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:minHeight="20dp"
        android:title="Bookmark This"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/share"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:minHeight="20dp"
        android:title="Share This"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:minHeight="20dp"
        android:title="Save This"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/small"
        android:icon="@drawable/font3"
        android:minHeight="20dp">
This icon is not showing.
            />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/medium"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:minHeight="20dp"
            android:title="Medium font"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/big"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:minHeight="20dp"
            android:title="Big font"/>
    </item>

</menu>
```

My inflating code:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
  menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.newsdescriptionmenu, menu);
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you refer to [Menu documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html)"

> **Options menus**: The icon menus do not support item check marks and only
>   show the item's   condensed title. The expanded menus (only available
>   if six or more menu items are visible, reached via the 'More' item in
>   the icon menu) do not show item icons, and item check marks are
>   discouraged.

Since I cannot see how you inflate (what options, etc) your menus I can only assume that you don't see this item's icon as it is a sixth item and hits the expanded menu after 'More'.

Comment: yes i got it ..In expandable items only the text will come not the icon..Am i right.Thanks a lot ...

Answer (score 2):

Please check the following code snippet.

menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/Menu1"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="Menu 1"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/Menu2"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:title="Menu 2"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/Menu3"
        android:orderInCategory="3"
        android:title="Menu 3"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/submenu"
        android:orderInCategory="4"
        android:title="Sub menu">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/submenu1"
                android:title="Sub menu 1"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/submenu2"
                android:title="Sub menu 2"/>
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Add these lines in your `Activity Class`

```
public class MenuActivity extends Activity {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    new MenuInflater(getApplication()).inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return(super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu));
  }

  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.Menu1:
      Toast.makeText(this, "Menu 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;
    case R.id.Menu2:
      Toast.makeText(this, "Menu 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;
    case R.id.Menu3:
      Toast.makeText(this, "Menu 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;
    case R.id.submenu:
      Toast.makeText(this, "Sub menu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;
  }
  return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
 }
}
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menuItem1"
          android:icon="@drawable/menu_item1"
          android:title="@string/menu_item1" />
    <item android:id="@+id/menuItem2"
          android:icon="@drawable/menu_item2"
          android:title="@string/menu_item2" />
</menu>